# Counting number of elements in non-overlapping sub-intervals of array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, counting

I want to count the number of elements in **non-overlapping** subsequences of a list.for example, in lst shown below:

```
lst = [0.2,1.3,2.2,3.5]
L = 0.5
for x in lst:
lb = x   # lowebound
ub = x+L   # upperbound
print(lb,ub)
```

The output is

```
  0.2 0.7  count=1
  1.3 1.8  count=1
  2.2 2.7  count=1
  3.5 4.0  count=1
```

As we can see, these intervals are **non-overlapping**. Also,in each of the interval [lb, ub], we have only one element which belongs to lst so count = 1 per interval.
However there is a complex case as given below

```
 nlst = [0.2,0.6,2.2,3.8]
```

Using above code will create overlapping intervals which we do not want. for instance using above code, we get

```
  0.2 0.7
  0.6 1.1
  2.2 2.7
  3.8 4.3
```

Now since 0.6 is included in first [0.2,0.7] interval, there is an overlap which we do not want. The desired output is

```
  0.2 0.7   count = 2
  2.2 2.7   count = 1
  3.8 4.3   count = 1
```

This problem can be easily solved if the original array is broken down to sub-arrays however in the arrays containing thousands of numbers, such methods become computationally intensive. 
In the examples above, I am showing intervals as outputs which is just to explain my problem. I only want the count per interval.
Could I be helped?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `nlst` always sorted?

Comment: Yes. It is always sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
lst = [0.2, 0.6, 2.2, 3.8]
L = 0.5

count = None
counts = []
append = counts.append
ub = lst[0]

for x in lst:
    if x < ub:
        count += 1
    else:
        append(count)
        count = 1
        ub = x + L

counts = counts[1:] + [count]

print(counts)
```

Update: And if you want to collect the intervals as well:

```
lst = [0.2, 0.6, 2.2, 3.8]
L = 0.5

ival = count = None
ivals, counts = [], []
ival = (None, lst[0])

for x in lst:
    if x < ival[1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        ivals.append(ival)
        counts.append(count)
        ival = x, x + L
        count = 1

ivals = ivals[1:] + [ival]
counts = counts[1:] + [count]

print(ivals)
print(counts)
```

Alternatively, you can create a list with triples (lower bound, upper bound, count) in a similar way.

Comment: Hi @Cito, Thanks a lot. There is just a follow up question. How can I divide lst into sublists into those intervals? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
list = [0.2,0.3,0.4,2.2,2.3,3.5,3.8,3.9,7.1]
interval = 0.5
list.sort()
answer = []
def calculate (list):
  count = 1
  check = list[0]
  del list[0] 
  list_copy = [i for i in list]
  for index, item in enumerate(list_copy):
    if check + interval > list_copy[index] :
      count += 1
      list.remove(item)
  answer.append(count)
  if (len(list)):
    calculate(list)
  else:
    return 
calculate(list);
print answer
```

Comment: Hi Shyam, Could you please explain the meaning of 'if (len(list)): calculate(list)'? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We are just cutting short the array element by element and calling recursive function to iterate over array and check for sum , so checking length here means whether new shorter array is blank or not , if blank then move out else reduce further.